# Test for valid JSON in .NET

Tags: .net, ajax, json, ashx

Is there a way in .NET that I can test if a JSON string I am about to send back to the client is valid? I am using an ASHX handler that accepts a bunch of form variables and returns a chunk of JSON that gets interpreted by the client. One of the parameters in the JSON contains a block of html that despite encoding sometimes gets corrupted with characters that cause a JSON error on the client. I'd like to catch this before it goes and email the sys admin with the details.

**Additional info:**

*Target Framework 4.0*

*.ajax JQuery method used to send and read the response.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, one idea is to try deserializing it server side (with your JSON framework of choice, be it [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) or [JsonFx](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx)) before sending it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) and have something like `JObject.Parse(json)` in a try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

You could try to deserialize it using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class.